# Android Java Object Lists with Images

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

I have written simple code in Java and now I'm learning Android and trying to convert my code.

What I'm trying to do are making objects with Image.
Got thousands of objects (separated in different classes like "boxes" "cars" "main" etc.)
And I want to add each object Image, so I could use it later, like for example. `BMW_e30.Image();`

I will try to show all my code readable and understandable, If it's not please comment and tell me how to improve my Code.

First I will show you my code how it was running in simple Java(All Java code worked, but it was messy and hard to understand)

---

**BoxesHolder.class (Object Lists)**

```
public class BoxesHolder {

    public Integer boxes[] = new Integer[20];

    public BoxesHolder(){

        MakeBoxes();
        }


    public void BoxesMaker(int k, int a1, int k1, int a2){

        boxes[a1] = k;
        boxes[a2] = k1;
    }

    public void MakeBoxes(){

        int i =0; int j =1;
        BoxesMaker(10, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 1
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(20, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 2
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(30, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 3
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(40, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 4
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(50, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 5
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(60, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 6
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(70, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 7
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(80, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 8
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(90, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 9
        i +=2; j +=2;
        BoxesMaker(100, i, 0, j); // Boxes Level 10
        i +=2; j +=2;
    }
}
```

**ImagesHolder.class**

```
public class ImagesHolder {

       URL BoxLv1_2Icon = ImagesHolder.class.getResource("/BoxLv1_2.png");
       URL BoxLv3_4Icon = ImagesHolder.class.getResource("/BoxLv3_4.png");
       URL BoxLv5_6Icon = ImagesHolder.class.getResource("/BoxLv5_6.png");
       URL BoxLv7_8Icon = ImagesHolder.class.getResource("/BoxLv7_8.png");
       URL BoxLv9_10Icon = ImagesHolder.class.getResource("/BoxLv9_10.png");
    }
```

**Labels for Displaying Images in JPanel:**

```
Labels.BoxesLVL1Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv1_2Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL2Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv1_2Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL3Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv3_4Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL4Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv3_4Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL5Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv5_6Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL6Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv5_6Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL7Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv7_8Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL8Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv7_8Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL9Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv9_10Icon));
Labels.BoxesLVL10Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv9_10Icon));
```

**OnButtonClick(Function to add new Boxes)**

```
 if(ae.getSource() == jbtnBoxes){
            CarMain.main[2] += 1;
            CarMain.main[3] += 1;
            Statistic.statistic[1] +=1;
            Statistic.statistic[2] +=1;
            if(CarMain.main[2] == 5){
                CarMain.main[2] -= 5;
                if(CarMain.main[4] == 1){
                    Box.boxes[1] = Box.boxes[1] + 1;
                    Statistic.statistic[13] +=1;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 1 LVL box!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv1_2Icon));}                  
                if(CarMain.main[4] == 2){ 
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2)+1;
                    if (randomInt == 1){
                        Box.boxes[1] = Box.boxes[1] + 1;
                        Statistic.statistic[13] +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 1 LVL box!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv1_2Icon));}
                    if (randomInt == 2){
                        Box.boxes[3] = Box.boxes[3] + 1;
                        Statistic.statistic[14] +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 2 LVL box!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv1_2Icon));}
                    }
```

Lines for Adding values(Count) :

```
Box.boxes[1] = Box.boxes[1] + 1;

Box.boxes[3] = Box.boxes[3] + 1;
```

Line for Displaying Images:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 1 LVL box!", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(ImagesHolder.BoxLv1_2Icon));}
```

**And now what I'm trying to do in Android Studio**

---

**BoxHolder.class**

```
package com.crelix.crelix;

public class BoxHolder {

    int id;
    String name;
    int level;
    int price;
    int sellprice;
    int count;

    public void id(int id) {

    }

    public BoxHolder(String name) {

    }

    public void level(int level) {

    }

    public void price(int price) {

    }

    public void sellprice(int sellprice) {

    }

    public void count(int count) {

    }


        public static void main(String args[]) {

            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxOne = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-1");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxTwo = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-2");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxThree = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-3");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxFour = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-4");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxFive = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-5");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxSix = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-6");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxSeven = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-7");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxEight = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-8");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxNine = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-9");
            BoxHolder AccessoriesBoxTen = new BoxHolder("Accessories Pack LV-10");

 AccessoriesBoxOne.id(1);
            AccessoriesBoxOne.level(1);
            AccessoriesBoxOne.price(10);
            AccessoriesBoxOne.sellprice(5);
            AccessoriesBoxOne.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxTwo.id(2);
            AccessoriesBoxTwo.level(2);
            AccessoriesBoxTwo.price(20);
            AccessoriesBoxTwo.sellprice(10);
            AccessoriesBoxTwo.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxThree.id(3);
            AccessoriesBoxThree.level(3);
            AccessoriesBoxThree.price(30);
            AccessoriesBoxThree.sellprice(15);
            AccessoriesBoxThree.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxFour.id(4);
            AccessoriesBoxFour.level(4);
            AccessoriesBoxFour.price(40);
            AccessoriesBoxFour.sellprice(20);
            AccessoriesBoxFour.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxFive.id(5);
            AccessoriesBoxFive.level(5);
            AccessoriesBoxFive.price(50);
            AccessoriesBoxFive.sellprice(25);
            AccessoriesBoxFive.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxSix.id(6);
            AccessoriesBoxSix.level(6);
            AccessoriesBoxSix.price(60);
            AccessoriesBoxSix.sellprice(30);
            AccessoriesBoxSix.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxSeven.id(7);
            AccessoriesBoxSeven.level(7);
            AccessoriesBoxSeven.price(70);
            AccessoriesBoxSeven.sellprice(35);
            AccessoriesBoxSeven.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxEight.id(8);
            AccessoriesBoxEight.level(8);
            AccessoriesBoxEight.price(80);
            AccessoriesBoxEight.sellprice(40);
            AccessoriesBoxEight.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxNine.id(9);
            AccessoriesBoxNine.level(9);
            AccessoriesBoxNine.price(90);
            AccessoriesBoxNine.sellprice(45);
            AccessoriesBoxNine.count(0);

            AccessoriesBoxTen.id(10);
            AccessoriesBoxTen.level(10);
            AccessoriesBoxTen.price(100);
            AccessoriesBoxTen.sellprice(50);
            AccessoriesBoxTen.count(0);
```

And I want to add Images like AccessoriesBoxOne.Image(ImageUrl); How can I do that?

How can I access objects now? Can't understand becouse these lines wont work anymore:

```
Box.boxes[1] = Box.boxes[1] + 1;
```

And I was thinking that I will do it in this way:

```
Box.AccessoriesBoxOne.count = +1;
```

But it doesn't work.

I hope that you will understand what I'm trying to say and trying to do, with hope, Crelix.

Comment: Variable names which differ only by a number mean that you should use an array or List. Please look for tutorials about these fundamental programming concepts.

Comment: Also this is not an android question since you are using JPanel.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm not using JPanel in new code(Code bellow), JPanel code is from simple Java coding in eclipse

Comment: I do not understand what you need help with. What is your question? Part of the difficult is that there is to much code here. Can you reduce it to a very simple example?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ok, I will do It now. Problem is there, that with new cod e (BoxHolder) not (BoxesHolder) wont work this " Box.boxes[1] = Box.boxes[1] + 1;" and I'm trying to to that with "Box.AccessoriesBoxOne.count = +1;" but it still don't work.

Comment: What does "don't work" mean?

Comment: It shows error in code and I can't compile. Image : http://imgur.com/a/1sHl9

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message here. You can click on the build button in the toolbar.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "Cannot resolve symbol Money"  in Line : CarMain.Money.count +=1; Yes I can, press button, but gradle shows error "Error:(12, 26) error: constructor MainHolder in class MainHolder cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: Please post a new question. Be sure to include the error messages, the lines of code that cause them, and enough additional code to provide context, but not too much code as to distract from getting the help you need.

Answer (score 2):

So, this code is of poor quality and hard to understand.

1. Read about DRY, loops, arrays and collections.
2. You should also use naming convention.
3. Use meaningful names: `k, k1, a, a2` - what it means?
4. Use private fields and getters/setters.

If you can, use primitive `int` array, instead of `Integer` array:

`int[] boxes = new int[20];` and then `Box.boxes[1]++` (incrementation)

Comment: Thanks, but if I understood right, these points are about "Simple Java Code" (I wont be working anymore with it), I need to know how to increment in Android code (Listed Bellow in topic).

Comment: And How I said Box.boxes[1] = Box.boxes[1] + 1 . Was working in simple Java, I just don't want to use that code.

Comment: Are you trying to use BoxHolder (last code in your question) in Android?

Comment: You have main() method, which in Android is not used. Do you have some Activity class and layout file in your Android project?

Comment: Yes, i have. I have mainActivity with activity_main.xml

Comment: In BoxHolder should be constructor with parameters, where you can set values of fields. All BoxHolders should be stored in some array or List.

Comment: Like in BoxesHolder (Up in topic?) Where I got BoxesMaker, etc?